# How to use Automapper to map an object to an interface at a different level?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm new to Automapper and am trying to map the data from an object in a list to an interface in a list.  Add to that the lists are in different levels of the containing objects:

```
// class definitions
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ViewModelId { get; set; }
    public IList<ViewItem> Page1Selections { get; set; }
    public IList<ViewItem> Page2Selections { get; set; }
}

public class ViewItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbModel
{
    public int DbModelId { get; set; }
    public IPageSelection Page1Selections { get; set; }
    public IPageSelection Page2Selections { get; set; }
}

public interface IPageSelection
{
    int PageNumber { get; set; }
    IList<IMyDbItem> PageSelections { get; set; }
}

public class PageSelection : IPageSelection
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<IMyDbItem> PageSelections { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyDbItem
{
    int ItemId { get; set; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbItem : IMyDbItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}


    // mapping code
    MyViewModel myVm = new MyViewModel();
    myVm.ViewModelId = 123;
    myVm.Page1Selections = new List<ViewItem>();
    myVm.Page1Selections.Add(new ViewItem() { ItemId = 1, IsSelected = true });
    myVm.Page2Selections = new List<ViewItem>();
    myVm.Page2Selections.Add(new ViewItem() { ItemId = 2, IsSelected = true });

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        cfg.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyDbModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap<ViewItem, IMyDbItem>();
    });

    MyDbModel myDb = new MyDbModel();
    myDb = Mapper.Map<MyDbModel>(myVm); //<== exception here
```

Sorry for the long attachment.  But I'm fighting both an object to interface and hierarchical mismatch mapping problem.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the problem you're encountering? Is there an error/crash/exception/break? Is there unexpected behavior? Is the code just incomplete?

Comment: I'm getting an exception: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types:
List`1 -> IPageSelection...  There's more but it's clear to me that the problem comes from Automapper trying to map IList<ViewItem> to IPageSelection. The list I want IList<ViewItem> to map to is one level deeper: IList<IMyDbItem> (under IPageSelection). Plus it's an interface. It's unclear to me how to configure the mapping instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could accomplish this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyDbModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DbModelId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ViewModelId));

cfg.CreateMap<ViewItem, IMyDbItem>()
    .ConstructUsing((ViewItem src) => new MyDbItem());

cfg.CreateMap<IList<ViewItem>, IPageSelection>()
    .ConstructUsing((IList<ViewItem> src) => new PageSelection())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PageSelections, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PageNumber, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

The error you were getting is because no mapping existed from `IList<ViewItem>` to `IPageSelection`. I've created that mapping above.

An important bit is the `ConstructUsing` calls. I added those here because I assumed you wanted to use the concrete types that implement the interfaces you're mapping to. Otherwise, AutoMapper will create a proxy class that implements the destination interface.

The part that enables mapping to the `IPageSelection.PageSelections` from `IList<ViewItem>` is the `opt.MapFrom(src => src)` part. This essentially tells AutoMapper to map from the list to the inner `PageSelections` property, ultimately using the mapping from `ViewItem` to `IMyDbItem`.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/DW9dfO